# How to open google spreadsheet using script and partial filename

Tags: google-apps-script

My goal is to get a partial filename from a cell(B2) using a script and find the complete URL, put the resulting URL in cell B3 so I can run a series of queries in the data. I've spent more hours searching google than I care to admit on this. I'm sure the answer is there but my in-experience with google scripting is preventing me from seeing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and provide [mcve]. And if you receive an answer that helps you to resolve your problem please check it off so that everyone can see that the problem is resolved. Generally, we like to see the code that you have are having a problem with and a description of what you have tried. If you successfully integrate all of these suggestions into your question then your much more likely to get a quick resolution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Files of a Feather

The feather is the partial string which must be provided.  You can use a [prompt](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) if you want it to be interactive with a user.

```
function getFilesOfAFeather(feather) {
  var files=DriveApp.getFiles();
  var fA=[];
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file=files.next();
    if(file.getName().indexOf(feather)>-1) {
      fA.push({name: file.getName(), id: file.getId(), url: file.getUrl()});
    }
  }
  return fA;        
}
```

- If `fA.length=0` then no files were found.
- If `fA.length=1` then var url=fA[0].url;
- If `fA.length>1` then you have to pick which one you want

```
    function findUrl() {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
      var feather=sh.getRange('B2').getValue();
      var f=getFilesOfAFeather(feather);
      if(f.length==1) {
        return f[0].url;
      }else{
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Utilities.formatString('Number of files found: ',f.length));
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm kind of lost. How to I reference this function to cell B2 where the partial filename will be entered.

Comment: I am getting the following error: #ERROR! You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFiles. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.

Comment: If the spreadsheets are in different accounts you'll need to share them.

Comment: I just tested both solutions on a file that I own with the same error. Do I need to add the googleapis.com statement in the google script somewhere. I do appreciate your help with this.

Comment: My answer does not contain two different solutions.  The second one calls the first one.  We make an assumption here on SO that you know JavaScript.  If that's not true then you should learn JavaScript.

Comment: Try enabling Drive API in Script Editor/Resources/Advanced Google Editor.  Actually, I'm not sure if that is necessary for DriveApp but give it a shot it won't hurt anything.  You'll also have to enable it in Google Cloud Platform API Console.  There is a link to it at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I enabled the Drive API as you suggested with no luck. I will see if I can come up with different plan. Again, thank you for your suggestions